# Voice Recording/Playback on Web for mobile(Android, iOS, BB)

Tags: iphone, android, html, blackberry, audio-recording

I am working on a website that works across all mobile browsers specifically Android, iOS and BB. I have used the experimental jQuery mobile for the consistent look and feel. One of the pages require audio to be recorded and played back for this I did some research and found that HTML5 has support for this but still part of the spec so it may not available on these browsers yet, so I was wondering if there is any workaround for this. I atleast know of one such application that captures audio and its Google Voice for iPhone and I read somewhere that they use HTML5 so does that mean safari has support for HTML5 audio capture? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

For audio playback, you can use this test page on all of your supported platforms and browsers.  It should confirm which HTML5 audio playback constructs will work:
http://www.jplayer.org/HTML5.Audio.Support/

It sounds like there are issues with even getting playback to work on Android, see here for info:
http://textopiablog.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/browser-support-for-html5-audio/

I haven't seen anything about current browser support for audio recording through HTML5.  You could try Java or Flash, but Java requires the user to have it installed (and accept suitable permissions), and Flash requires you to set up a server for the data to be sent to (e.g. Red5)...and remember that Flash does not work on iOS.

Comment: one up, is this statement "I haven't seen anything about current browser support for audio recording through HTML5" still true?

Comment: I've heard good things about WebSockets, but I haven't investigated it myself (and I'm not even sure if it is definitely part of HTML5 or not!): http://www.mobicules.com/web-application-development/websockets-in-html5/

Comment: this is still the case for anyone who finds this comment but thanks @dan